# Access Creating sum(iif to get the number of periods which apply

Tags: ms-access

I'm trying to make a sum iif function which checks based on an employee's hire date and the ending pay period date whether they are part of the payroll period. So my idea was sum(iif([table1].[hiredate]<=[table2].[ppend],1,0))
While it works well for some, for some employees the number it gives is ridiculous. To give you an idea, there are 200 records for ppend, but it returns for some employees especially those who are well before the earliest ppend date, a number of 400 upward to 450. I'm also attempting to have it compare relative to the current date as well so I've used sum(iif(table1.hiredate<=table2.ppend<=date(),1,0)) but it largely leads to the same result. Could anybody help. Perhaps there is a factor I've neglected.
For table 1 the column data is in this order: employee ID, name, hire date and table 2 is payroll date, pp beg, pp end.

Comment: You better post your query.

Comment: Please share what you have tried so far, and try to format your queries in code format provided by StackOverflow

Comment: Employees and pay periods are for sure not linked. If there are 200 payment periods and some employees show 400 payment periods, then your query either has at least one table linked to the employees or to the payment periods that multiplies the records. The triple condition will never work (always evaluete to true), because `date1 <= date2` will evaluate to `True` or `False` (`-1` or `0`) and you can be sure that both of them are `<= date()`. Post your query.

Comment: I believe I fixed the issue. It appears it was a rather simple solution and silly mistake on my part. When creating the query using test data, and then adding in the table full of the actual data (all done through design view) I neglected to remove the previous table from the statement. Thanks everybody for the assistance, and sorry for wasting your time. Thanks Wolf for pointing that out, I had neglected to check if I removed the other tables from the sql query, as while it isn't there in the design view, it was still in the query.